# How to run python file with its dependencies on ros2?

Tags: python, ros, ros2

I am working with ROS2 python. When I run the code from VS code, my python code is working. However it is not working with running from terminal as ros2 run command. It can not find the dependencies beginning of the python file. Beginning of the python file, I am calling the another python file inside the another folder. Is this error related to CMakeList.txt file? You can see the path from attached [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mE1i.png). When sub_UNITY_YOLOSORT.py runs, it calls another python code inside Yolov5_StrongSORT_OSNet folder.

Comment: This might help: https://answers.ros.org/question/349790/ros2-python-relative-import-of-my-scritps/ or this https://answers.ros.org/question/367793/including-a-python-module-in-a-ros2-package/